# Assign index of deleted product

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate

I have a simple jQuery script that allows user to add products to basket and see the animation.
http://jsfiddle.net/Z6ave/7/

Now, I have a slight problem and just can't seem to find a plausible solution.

As you can see in the code, when you add a product to basket, the order attribute gets assigned:

```
Product that was added 1st - Order 1
Product that was added 2nd - Order 2
Product that was added 3rd - Order 3
Product that was added 4th - Order 4
Product that was added 5th - Order 5
Product that was added 6th - Order 6
```

and so on...
and that's fine, every position has a certain CSS rule attached to it.

But, if I delete some product in the middle or any other that isn't the last one, and when I add another one after that, I need it to fill the empty place.

What happens right now is this...
If I delete product number 3 from the list above, and add another one after that, the list will look like this:

```
Product that was added 1st - Order 1
Product that was added 2nd - Order 2
Product that was added 4th - Order 4
Product that was added 5th - Order 5
Product that was added 6th - Order 6
Product that was added 7th - Order 7
```

You see that the problem is the empty space of number 3, so the 7 should actually go under 3.

Can you help me with this one? I know there must be some easy/elegant solution.

Thank you

Comment: +1 for the example :)

Comment: Your question seems contradictory - if item 7 was placed in slot 3, your system would say it was added 3rd, but it wasn't. If you want to keep the order of the way the items were added, you would be better off regenerating the order each time an item is removed before adding the new item to the end.

Comment: I see your point, I guess I wasn't clear enough. I need that seventh element to be recognized as third when there is a third space left available.

Comment: You could make an array of the delete items - when one is deleted it is added to the array - then if the array is not empty use the first item in the array for the number, and remove that from the array, or if it is empty then just use the next number, if you understand what i mean. don't have time to put together an example right now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i added a comment earlier. here is an example of doing it via an array : http://jsfiddle.net/Z6ave/8/

i created an array `var removedArray = [];`

then when you delete an item it adds to the array:

> ```
> $(".del").live("click", function() {
> var removed = $(this).parent().attr("order");
> removedArray.push(removed);
> $(this).parent().remove(); });
> ```

and uses this when creating an element

```
if(removedArray.length > 0){

  var deletedNumber = removedArray[0];

  inbasketimage.addClass("slot" + deletedNumber);
  inbasketimage.attr("order", deletedNumber);
  inbasketimage.find("img").attr("src", img.attr("src"));
  inbasketimage.attr("product_name", productName);

  removedArray.shift();

}else{

  if(isNaN(order)) {
    order = 1;
  } else {
    order = order + 1;
  }

  inbasketimage.addClass("slot" + order);
  inbasketimage.attr("order", order);
  inbasketimage.find("img").attr("src", img.attr("src"));
  inbasketimage.attr("product_name", productName);
}
```

Comment: Wow, that helped me a lot. Thanks a million.
I made just a simple tweak by adding removedArray.sort() just before the deleted item initialization. http://jsfiddle.net/Z6ave/9/